# increment and decrement quantity on cart in node js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, fetch-api

I have been trying two days to update my cart product quantity by using the onclick function, I am not sure where it went wrong. I updated the onclick increment and decrement functions which is not responding.

button click

```
<div class="input-group-btn">

    <button  onclick=" qty('<%= prdct.item._id %>','<%= prdct.item.saleprice %>',-1,'<%= prdct.item.stock %>', this.parentNode.querySelector('.form-control'),document.querySelector('#subtotal'))" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-minus" >
    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-secondary text-center" value="<%= prdct.quantity %>">
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button onclick=" qty('<%= prdct.item._id %>','<%= prdct.item.saleprice %>',1,'<%= prdct.item.stock %>', this.parentNode.querySelector('.form-control'),document.querySelector('#subtotal'))" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-plus">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

qty function

```
async function qty(id, price, q, prdctQty, input, subtotal) {
  try {
    console.log(id, q, price);


    // const response = await fetch(`/cart/add-product/change_qty?prdctId=${id}&&val=${q}&&price=${price}&&productQty=${prdctQty}`, {
    //   method: 'GET',
    // });
    const response = await fetch('/cart/add-product/change_qty', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        prdctId: id,
        val: q,
        price: price,
        productQty: prdctQty,
      }),
    });
    alert('get');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    
    let newQty = data.qty < 1 ? 1 : data.qty;
    input.value = newQty;
    input.value = data.qty;
    subtotal.innerHTML = data.sub_total;
    
    const totalElement = document.querySelector('#total');
    totalElement.innerHTML = data.total;
    console.log(data.total);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('something went wrong');
  }
}
```

function to change quantity(cart controller)

```
const change_qty = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const prdctId = req.query.prdctId;
    const val = parseInt(req.query.val);
    const user_id = req.session.user_id;
    const productQty = req.query.productQty;
    
    console.log(reach )
    // Find the cart
    const cartData = await Cart.findOne({ user_id: user_id }).populate('product.item');

    // Check if the product already exists in the cart
    let foundProduct = null;
    for (let prdct of cartData.product) {
      if (prdct.item._id == prdctId) {
        foundProduct = prdct;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!foundProduct) {
      // If the product is not found, respond with an error
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Product not found' });
    }
    if (isNaN(val) || val <= 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid quantity' });
    }
    // if (val > product.stock) {
    //   return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Quantity exceeds available stock' });
    // }

    let qty = foundProduct.quantity + val < 1 ? 1 : foundProduct.quantity + val;
    qty = qty >= productQty ? productQty : qty;
    const prodctPrice = req.query.price;
    const sub_total = qty * prodctPrice;

    foundProduct.sub_total = sub_total;
    foundProduct.quantity = qty;

    // Save the updated cart
    await cartData.save();

    // Calculate the total amount
    let total = 0;
    cartData.product.forEach(amnt => {
      total += amnt.sub_total;
    });
    cartData.total_amount = total;

    // Save the cart with updated total amount
    await cartData.save();

    res.json({ qty, sub_total, total });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
};
```

This is my cart controller and my progress with the code, please suggest me a way to update the quantity by onclick + and - on my product which is on cart.

Comment: So, what DOES happen?  Do you see the console log messages? Are you getting to the server st all?  Your HTML snipped is using PHP's templating.  What template processor are you using?

Comment: I'm not getting anything out of console logs either in cart controller. When the fetch statement is executed, the change-qty function is not invoked. I'm using ejs view engine, using node js and mongodb , this is part of my project, where I'm stuck for two days. Items are added to cart but when+ or - buttons are pressed, the quantity number is not getting incremented or decremented.

Comment: Where do you set up the route?  Somewhere, you have to hook something up to `change_qty`.